# Compare objects in two arrays javascript any append missing

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to do some JSON function where I need to compare objects in array1 and array2 like below and append the missing one to either array2 or create a newArray1 altogether.

here is the example

```
const array1 = [
   {
      "document_id":"ABC123",
      "document_title":"How to solve a Status",
   },
   {
      "document_id":"ABC678",
      "document_title":"Make it Status two",
   },
  {
      "document_id":"ABC678",
      "document_title":"Make it Status two",
   }
];

const array2 = [
   {
      "article_id":"ABC123",
      "rank":0
   },
   {
      "article_id":"ABC678",
      "rank":1
   }
]

const resultOutput = [{
      "article_id":"ABC123",
      "rank":0,
      "title":"How to solve a Status",
   },
   {
      "article_id":"ABC678",
      "rank":1,
      "title":"Make it Status two",
   }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. (Detailed explanation below the snippet.)

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    "document_id":"ABC123",
    "document_title":"How to solve a Status",
  },
  {
    "document_id":"ABC678",
    "document_title":"Make it Status two",
  },
  {
    "document_id":"ABC678",
    "document_title":"Make it Status two",
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    "article_id":"ABC123",
    "rank":0
  },
  {
    "article_id":"ABC678",
    "rank":1
  }
];

const mergedMap = ([...array1, ...array2])
.reduce(
  (acc, {document_id, article_id = document_id, ...others}) => {
    acc[article_id] = {...(acc[article_id] || {article_id}), ...others};
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(Object.values(mergedMap));
```

Create a new array with all of the entries from array1 and array2.

`[...array1, ...array2]`

Run [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the merged array.

```
[...array1, ...array2].reduce(
  // function,
  // initial value
)
```

The first argument to [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a function to be called for each item in the array. It takes 4 arguments, but we only care about the first two:

1. The value returned by the previous iteration (the accumulator)
2. The current array entry.

We're using [object destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) on the second argument (the current array entry) to get the `article_id` and defaulting it to `document_id`, and capturing the rest of the item's properties as `others`.

```
(acc, {document_id, article_id = document_id, ...others}) => {
```

Merge the current item's properties into the accumulator's entry for its `article_id`, creating the entry as necessary via `{article_id}`:

```
acc[article_id] = {...(acc[article_id] || {article_id}), ...others};
```

Return the updated accumulator for the next iteration:

```
return acc;
```

The end result of this reduce call will be a map of `article_id` to merged objects:

```
{
  ABC123: {
    article_id: 'ABC123',
    rank: 0,
    title: 'How to solve a Status',
  },
  ABC678: {
    article_id: 'ABC678',
    document_title: 'Make it Status two',
    rank: 1
  }
}
```

We don't care about the keys in this object anymore, so we extract the values as an array:

```
Object.values(mergedMap);
```

Which gets us the array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "article_id": "ABC123",
    "document_title": "How to solve a Status",
    "rank": 0
  },
  {
    "article_id": "ABC678",
    "document_title": "Make it Status two",
    "rank": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use nested for loops like this...

```
const resultOutput = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    let currentObj = array2[$i];

    for(let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        if(currentObj.article_id === array1[j].document_id) {
            let tempObj = {
                "article_id": currentObj.article_id,
                "rank": currentObj.rank,
                "title": array1[j].document_title
            };

            resultOutput.push(tempObj);
        }
    }
}
```